# Do prime elements generate a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $p_1, p_2, p_3 \in R$ are prime elements, does it follow that $\left<p_1,p_2,p_3\right>$ will be a prime ideal?

Comment: It may be that $< p_1, p_2, p_3 > =R$. For example, take $p1=2$, $p_2=3$, $p_3=5$ inside the ring of integers.

Comment: so what if $<p_1,p_2,p_3> \neq R$?

Comment: Why would a sum of prime ideals be prime?

Comment: It is worth trying to prove that if $p$ is a prime element of a domain, the principal ideal generated by it is a prime ideal.  It is pretty immediate from the definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: this is not true even for $n \ge 2$ prime elements. A counterexample follows:

let $R= \Bbb{C}[X,Y]$. By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz we know that radical ideals of $R$ are in bijection with algebraic subsets of $\Bbb{C}^2$. Moreover, prime ideals correspond to irreducible algebraic sets. Now, if you consider the family of "complex parabolas" with equations
$$y= ax^2-a \ \ \ \ \ a \in \Bbb{C}$$
all of these correspond to prime elements of $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]$, namely $\{ Y- aX^2+a\}_{a \in \Bbb{C}}$. Denote these elements by $\{ p_a \}_{a \in \Bbb{C}}$. All these belong to $m_1 \cap m_2$, where
$$m_1 = \langle X-1, Y\rangle\ \ \ , \ \ \ m_2 = \langle X+1, Y\rangle$$
which are maximal ideals of $R$: indeed all the parabolas have in common exactly two points: $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Fix now finitely many distinct complex numbers $a_k$ with $k = 1, \dots , n$, and consider the ideal $\langle p_{a_1}, \dots , p_{a_n} \rangle$ : this is a sum of prime ideals, hence it corresponds to the intersection of the corresponding parabolas. But this intersection is given by the union of the two points above, which is not irreducible: in other words
$$\langle p_{a_1}, \dots , p_{a_n} \rangle = m_1 \cap m_2$$
and this is not a prime ideal of $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]$.

Comment: Note: Obviously if $R$ is a domain of dimension $1$, any two prime ideals are comaximal, hence the sum of prime ideals turns out to be the whole ring. For this purpose, I needed to construct a counterexample using a ring of dimension $2$ (the OP wanted the further assumption that the sum of prime ideals were a proper ideal).